# Why does glass break at the line where you score it?

Tags: material-science, stress-strain

Why does it take such a small incision for the glass to break at that spot? Why is the structural strength of the material influenced by such a small imperfection?

Comment: Well, because glass is uniform in thickness and the force needed to break it is proportional to the thickness - or some increasing function, whatever it is. An incision means that the thickness at that point could be 1% or 10% smaller so the fource needed to break it at that point is 1% or 10% smaller than elsewhere. If one continuously increases the force - and any realistic contact has a nonzero time when the force is continuously increasing - it's therefore guaranteed that the glass will break at that point.

Comment: i'm not sure if the force needed is proportional with the thickness. Could the glass start to crack at one end and sort of unzip itself to the other end. For a normal unscored glass this unzipping couldn't take place because it doesn't have a clear path. If this unzipping is really happening then the force should be just enough to start the crack, which I believe is much small then the force needed to break the whole length of glass at the same time as it would happen with a normal pane of glass

Comment: What is wrong with the description at [Fracture Mechanics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fracture_mechanics)?

Comment: Right, of course, I meant the force needed to start the crack. Once the shape begins to change and bonds are broken, the situation and required forces for further steps change - and have to be recalculated again. Yes, it's then very likely that the breaking will continue along a path.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick thanks for the reference, I was not aware of 'fracture mechanics' terminology/field

Answer (score 9):

Suppose you bend a perfect, i.e. unscratched, piece of glass, the forces on it look like:

[image: bend glass]

The top of the glass is in tension and the bottom in compression, but the stress is spread over a large area of glass so the local stress at any point isn't enough to break the glass.

Now put a scratch in the top surface and bend it again:

[image: bend scratch]

This time the stress is concentrated at the leading edge of the scratch so you get a high local stress and the glass breaks at the tip of the scratch. This means the crack grows until it breaks through the glass. That's why putting a scratch on the glass causes it to break when bent. The scratch focusses the stress at the scratch.